# WP_Query to display posts by category in Wordpress (in custom post types)

Tags: wordpress

Hej, I'll keep it short. I want to output this in a WP loop:

```
Support
    Category1
      -Post1
      -Post2
    Category2
      -PostA
      -PostB
      -PostC
```

So I want to order posts by category that are located in a custom post type - `support` (created thanks to Types plugin, link: ujeb.se/A4zqZ ).

I have this:

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'support');
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>

    <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

My `$query` stores all the necessary posts from my custom post type (`support`) but I have a problem with displaying them by category. I believe I need some sort of `foreach` but I can't really figure it out. Any suggestions?

/edit/
The current display looks like this:

```
Support, Category1
Post1
---
Support, Category2
PostA
---
Support, Category1
Post2

etc.
```

Comment: Try replacing `while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>` with  `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>`. Also instead of endwhile use endif.In your $args you need something like `'orderby' => array( 'postcol' => 'DESC', 'categorycol' => 'DESC' )`

Comment: Thanks for the try, but changing the `while` loop to an `if` changes the output to `Support` :<

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how you do it. You needed a foreach loop to cycle through the categories.

```
<?php
$cats = get_categories();

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'support',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $cat->cat_ID,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <p><?php echo $cat->cat_name ; ?></p> <?

   while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <p><?php the_content(); ?></p> <?php
   endwhile;
endif; 

// Added this now 
wp_reset_query() ; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :( It gets all the categories and disregards the `support` post type so I also get unrelated posts/categories.

Comment: Hmm, how do I got about resetting the query? I tried to put `wp_reset_query();` in a few places but nothing really changed. I have taken a closer look at what actually gets output-ed and I get all categories I have (those from `support` and those unrelated) and each one of them has the same set of posts, which are the `support` posts.

Comment: `usort()` + `the_posts` filter. Search my profile, I have recently done something similar ;-)

Comment: Worked, thanks! A quick followup question (although I can probably figure this out on my own), how do I exclude a category? I tried to add `'cat' => '-excludeme',` to the array but it didn't work.

Comment: Simply add the operator key like this to the `$args`  as another param  `array(
   'taxonomy' => 'category',
   'field'    => 'term_id',
   'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
   'operator' => 'NOT IN',
  ),`

Answer (score 2):

this work for me:

```
   $posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'category_name' => 'news,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        ));
```